# Perl failing to create cgi session

Tags: perl, session-state

I have the code as shown below. A BEGIN which loads the session or, if none is yet created, it creates one. But it doesn't do it all the time. It's a login script; If I enter the PIN and it's wrong, the script displays the login form again, which is submitted to this same script. Up to 3 attempts permitted but, it will fail to load the session, usually on attempt 2. Inconsistent so, please can anyone see what might be wrong and why is the session sometimes not loading.

I do have warnings enabled and I have shown that in the code.
I used to start the script with 'print $session->header' but, having changed to 'print $cgi->header;' I can see clearly that the session is undefined, when the script fails.  I should add that, if I refresh the failed page perhaps as many as 5 times, the session does eventually reload with all data intact.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#use CGI::Carp qw/warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser/;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use CGI qw(:all);
use CGI::Session;
use Crypt::PasswdMD5;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper; 


my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $session;
my $sessions_dir_location;
my $session_id;

BEGIN{
  unshift @INC, "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subDomain.example.com/cgi-bin/library";
  
  my $document_root = $ENV{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'};
  $document_root =~ s/\///;
  my ( $var
     , $www
     , $vhosts 
     , $domain 
     ) = split ('/', $document_root, 5);

  $sessions_dir_location = '/' . $var . '/' . $www . '/' . $vhosts . '/' . $domain;
    
  $session = CGI::Session->load() or die CGI::Session->errstr();
  if ( $session->is_expired ) {
    print $session->header(),
          $cgi->start_html(),
          $cgi->p("Your session timed out! Refresh the screen to start new session!"),
          $cgi->end_html();
    exit(0);
  }

  if ( $session->is_empty ) {
      $session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, 
  {Directory=>"$sessions_dir_location/sessions_storage/"}) or die CGI::Session->errstr;
  }
  
 

#add the library dir to @INC;
use lib do {
use Cwd 'realpath';
my ($dir) = __FILE__ =~ m{^(.*)/};  
realpath("$dir/library"); 
};


use feature 'say';
use FindBin '$RealBin';
use lib $RealBin;
use lib "$RealBin/library";
}

my $self = $cgi->url;
my %login = $cgi->Vars;



print $cgi->header;
   
# capture and display warnings
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
my $message = shift;
print $cgi->header;
print qq($message);  
};

print qq(<pre>);
print Dumper \%login;
print qq(</pre>);    
print qq(<pre>session);
print Dumper \$session;  #undef
print qq(</pre>); 

#next is line 141
my $session_stored_user_name = $session->param("entered_user_name");
```

Error message is this:

`Can't call method "param" on an undefined value at /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subDomain.example.com/cgi-bin/dashboard-login/login-with-pin.pl line 141, <DAT> line 45.`

Please, also, what or where is <DAT> line 45?

Comment: Is the code you posted `login-with-pin.pl`?  What's on line 141?  That's the first place to start looking.

Comment: The error message you posted doesn't line up with the code you posted. Does the code you posted exhibit the problem? If not, please fix the question to include (minimal, runnable) code that does. Either way, fix your question so that the error message is one actually produced by the code you posted.

Comment: the DAT line 45 part is not necessarily relevant. It means you have a file handle open named `DAT` from which 45 lines have been read. Possibly something used by one of the modules.

Comment: Apologies. OP edited to include the line that is erroring.It errors because the session is not being loaded.

Comment: I removed the session load (etc) section to outside (and after) the BEGIN block, which appears to have fixed my fundamental issue, however, I still get a browser created page quite often, saying 'DATA not Sent'. Perhaps the cause for that is elsewhere.  (Chrome on Ubuntu fyi.)

Comment: What execution environment is the script running under?  If you are using mod_perl or any persistent environment, the BEGIN block will only run once at script startup.  It won't run again until the script is reloaded by a new thread or other trigger.

Comment: `$cgi` is initialized in the run phase (outside the `BEGIN` block) but used in the compile phase (inside the `BEGIN` block)? That's not going to end well.

Comment: Thank you very much, mob. I have now moved it inside the BEGIN block. None of the warnings highlighted that as an error though so I probably might not have seen that myself. Not able to mark your comment as good :(